# python subprocess dpkg : I'm getting errors for something that runs in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to emulate the following bash command using subprocess :

```
dpkg --get-selections > a_file.txt
```

I've been trying things in the Python interpreter :

#### 1 just running dpkg

```
>>> args = ['dpkg','--get-selections']
>>> subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

#### 2 assigning subprocess to a variable

```
>>> x = subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

#### 3 redirecting subprocess output to a file

```
>>> args = ['dpkg','--get-selections', '>', 'a_file.txt']
>>> subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

#### 4 redirection included as one argument in the array

```
>>> args = ['dpkg','--get-selections', '> a_file.txt']
>>> subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

#### 5 without using `shell=True`

```
>>> x = subprocess.call(args)
dpkg: no packages found matching > a_file.txt
>>>
```

I can't seem to get anything concrete about the `dpkg: error: need an action option` in relation to using it within subprocess.

The bash command works fine, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the syntax either.

cheers

Comment: Ugh, why are you using output redirection like this? That's a horrible idea. Pass a file object via the `stdout` kwarg instead!

Comment: @ThiefMaster because I know no better - I'll have a look at the `stdout kwarg` you mentioned

Comment: If you were using  `shell=True` you would pass a string `check_call("dpkg --get-selections > a_file.txt",shell=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `stdout` argument of `call()`. Also, you usually do not want `shell=True` - in most cases you don't need it to be executed in a shell and not using one is much safer (remember ShellShock?)!

```
args = ['dpkg', '--get-selections']
with open('a_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.call(args, stdout=outfile)
```

If you get an error from *dpkg* itself, it means you are passing the wrong arguments. This is not related to subprocess.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't really aware of `with` actually, nice  way of being able to write something. Going to read about the kwargs now, cheers.

Comment: I have to wait to select as answer (6 minutes). If you could give a hint as to why the original post was so urgh inducing that would be ace (though I'm not doubting it!). Is it a security issue or just the fact it's not so clean? thanks

Comment: It's just the fact that using shell-based output redirects in Python is quite ugly - about as bad as someone using `subprocess.call()` with a shell and `|` pipes. Usually if a language/library does something natively, it's not a good idea to use a shell or external tools for it.

Comment: I'll try not to use `|` in future `subprocess`es then :) Using things that are provided is logic even I can understand, cheers.